# AWS DMS - How can we replace carriage return and new line characters coming from source before uploading files to s3?

Tags: aws-dms

I have a DMS task bringing data from postgres and writing to S3. How can we replace special characters like carriage return and new line feed before uploading to S3 which is the target?
Attached are the endpoint settings for the task.
Thank you.

I have tried to find any parameters in endpoint settings which will use quote character for data but couldnt find any.